# Is this photo from an actual hot air balloon event? Which one?

Tags: locate-this

[image: balloon puzzle]

I did this balloon puzzle and was wondering if it was from a real event and what it was called.

The 'C' balloon i  particular  interests me, it looks like a company  logo. If anyone has any ideas I'd be very interested to know where it is from.

Comment: Some balloons are sponsored because of their advertising exposure.

Comment: The "C" is the logo of Colorado.

Comment: My guess is it's a painting or a graphic. It's very unlikely for so many balloons to be landing at the same time and place, so they must be setting off, but not many of them seem to be burning gas – not even the nearest one that is only a couple of feet off the lake. The distant balloon in the centre background must be downwind, but those in foreground over the lake have just taken taken off and so seem to be moving in the opposite direction. Although it's possible to have different wind direction at different altitude.

Comment: Landing may be unlikely; mass ascent, however, is not: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehrA-wOskMc

Comment: @WeatherVane I was going to say it reminded me of a hot air balloon festival my parents once took me to. The balloons didn't take off - they just showed off the balloons - don't ask me why. Point is, they had a lot of balloons in that amount of space.

Comment: @user253751 I don't dispute that: the balloons taking off are usually all in the same field or arena. I said they are not landing.

Comment: Having seen balloons start for a 'regular' good weather Saturday flight, 10's, not 100's, I do believe this can be a real photo, but enhanced and maybe more heavily edited. And not at the start but soon after.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the helpful comment by @Doc stating that the 'C' is in fact the Colorado logo, I was able  to google and find out this is in fact a real event, the Snowmass Balloon Festival in Aspen, Colorado!

https://blog.limelighthotels.com/drift-away-at-the-snowmass-balloon-festival/

The C balloon is even shown in this video from the 2015 festival:

https://youtu.be/QKGig9azayU

Screenshot of the video:

[image: balloon screenshot]

Comment: I still say that the picture isn't a real photo, even if there is an event in Colorado.

Comment: If you go to Google Images and enter "snowmass balloon festival images" you'll see the original photo that puzzle is based on as well as many others taken at that same festival at that lake.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't understand why you think the photo can't be real.  It's far from the only such event.  In St. Louis, Missouri, USA there's a "Balloon Glow" in the evening, followed by a hot-air balloon race the next day, every year (though probably not in 2020).  There are photos here: [The Great Forest Park Balloon Race](https://greatforestparkballoonrace.com/photo-contest/)

Comment: @Kyralessa I put some reasons in another comment. Obviously there are many balloon events with large numbers: I've even been to some. The fact that there are balloon events is no proof that this picture is real. IMO it is idealised: it's too 'clean' to be real.